# Android: how to share listview data using Intent.createChooser()

Tags: android, android-intent, android-actionbar

Hi in my app i have a fragment with listview and a spinner, i am getting the data into the listview from my database using the cursoradapter, i wanna share this listview data via email , i am implementing the shareintent action on my actionbar , but struck how to get the listview data into the intent chooser.

Below is my code:

```
 actionBar.addAction(new IntentAction(this, createShareIntent(), R.drawable.ic_title_share_default));

  private Intent createShareIntent() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Shared from the ActionBar widget.");
        return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share");
    }
```

Below is my cursorAdapter

```
public class bottomlistmonthlyvolume extends CursorAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    public bottomlistmonthlyvolume(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor topcursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView123);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.achievmentValue);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.shortfallValue);
    TextView et1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.actualvalue);
    TextView et2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.budgetvalue);

    tv1.setText(topcursor.getString(1));
    tv2.setText(topcursor.getString(7));
    tv3.setText(topcursor.getString(9));
    et1.setText(topcursor.getString(3));
    et2.setText(topcursor.getString(5));

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list_item, parent, false);


    }
}
```

can someone suggest how to implement it

Comment: Can you put you CursorAdapter code?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways:
1. To add a method to your `SQLiteOpenHelper` class (if you use it) that returns you a string with your data direct from database.
2. In you `CursorAdapter` class define a string member and each time you call `bindView` concatenate each list item data to that string.

If you post more code I can be more specific.

Edit:
So from your code you want to go on way 2:
Assume that you have a reference in your fragment that called `bottomlistmonthlyvolume mAdapter;`
In the adapter see the comments

```
public class bottomlistmonthlyvolume extends CursorAdapter {
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    StringBuilder shareData = new StringBuilder(); // container for shared data

    public bottomlistmonthlyvolume(Context context, Cursor c) {
    super(context, c);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor topcursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    TextView tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView123);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.achievmentValue);
    TextView tv3 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.shortfallValue);
    TextView et1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.actualvalue);
    TextView et2 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.budgetvalue);

    // Assume we want to share all 'achievmentValue' with a title
    shareData.append("YOUR TITLE").append(topcursor.getString(7)).append("\n");

    tv1.setText(topcursor.getString(1));
    tv2.setText(topcursor.getString(7));
    tv3.setText(topcursor.getString(9));
    et1.setText(topcursor.getString(3));
    et2.setText(topcursor.getString(5));

    }
    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {


    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list_item, parent, false);


    }

    public String getShareData(){
        return shareData.toString();
    }
}
```

And in the action bar:

```
actionBar.addAction(new IntentAction(this, createShareIntent(), R.drawable.ic_title_share_default));

  private Intent createShareIntent() {
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mAdapter.getShareData());
        return Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share");
    }
```

Comment: hi i updated my question with cursoradapter code. please check it.

Comment: hi as soon as i click on the sharebutton for first time it is not working ,when i change the activity and comeback to sharebutton its working.. whats happening

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Debug your code and see what happens when.

Comment: i am unable to find why the data is not loading the first time.

Comment: Try to put the ActionBar creation to onCreateView()

Comment: I also recomend you to read Fragment lifecycle:  http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html